# Trying to edit css, php files without ftp access

Tags: 7

I am trying to be able to edit files of my Drupal site without having to go in the 'back way' (such as SFTP, via PuTTY & Vi or Nano, etc).  Specifically to edit the theme and template files (e.g. *http.tpl.php*)

I read a suggestion for the [elfinder File Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/elfinder) module but ran into trouble when trying to enable the module.

Seems **elFinder** requires **elFinder BUEditor integration** and **elFinder File Field Source**.

But **elFinder BUEditor integration** and **elFinder File Field Source** requires **elFinder**.

So it fails to enable each time!

[image]

I'm not even sure that this will allow me to edit the .php files through the browser, or if there is any means to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: _elFinder_ does not require _elFinder BUEditor integration_ and _elFinder File Field Source_, it is **required by** those modules. Enabling them all at once should resolve your constraints. If that does not work, please provide us with an error message of some sort.

Comment: And why did you tag this with Drupal 8? The module version numbers indicate Drupal 7.

Comment: @Neograph734    Thank you for responding. 

Sorry about the tagging. I tried tagging it as "module" (it required something) and somehow the "8" got used instead.

Now I see the difference between the "Requires" and "Required by". My mistake.

The error I got was `elFinder library was not found. Please download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/elfinder/files/ and install to . (Currently using elFinder Not found)`

Comment: In that case read the module installation instructions again (Readme file or module page). You probably need in install the libraries API and download some more files.